# Proof of Adjoints

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, definition, determinant

In the proof of adjoints, it is sufficient to show $A(\frac{1}{det(A)} adj(A)) = I$.

It went through a series of co-factor expansion along the $i^{th} row$ and $j^{th} row$, and this resulted in

$A[adj(a)]=(b_{ij})_{n×n}$

$$ = 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        det(A) & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
        0 & det(A)  & \ddots & 0 \\
        1 & \vdots & \ddots & 0  \\
        1 & \cdots & 0 & det(A) \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$ 
= det(A)I
$$

and that's how it gets to $A(\frac{1}{det(A)} adj(A))$.

Now, the whole problem is I don't get the whole idea of the co-factor portion and also how does $(b_{ij})_{n×n}$ leads to the chunk of $det(A)$ identity matrix as shown above.

Thanks for the help. ^^

Comment: Do you know what $\frac{1}{\det(A)}adj(A)$ represents?

Comment: @mate89 Does it represent $A^{-1}$ since $A[\frac{1}{det(A)}adj(a)] = I$?

Comment: sure! that's a well known expression for $A^{-1}$.That should give you a hint of why it works and why you get $I$. Now, what's the original matrix $A$? or what is the proof about